# Ping with and Without WWW different results

Tags: dns, propagation

I recently updated my DNS to point to a new IP. When I ping the domain with and without www. I get different results (with the www I receive the old IP, without it I receive the new one). Is this just a DNS propagation issue in terms of timing? I have a catchall (*) set on the nameserver that the domain is pointing to.

Comment: have you tried flushing your dns cache ? which OS do you use ? for windows you can try "ipconfig /flushdns" for linux restart nscd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DNS, there are two records you need to update. It sounds like you updated the `root or @` record but there is also a `www` A record you need to update with the new IP.